# Writing an aggregate using yaml dsl in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am a newbie to apache camel and trying to dapple with using yaml dsl for writing an aggregation. I simply need to read all files from multiple directories and aggregate the files per directory.
I am trying to acghive this using yaml dsl and apache camel v 3.20.0
my route dsl:

```
route:    
      id: id1
      from: 
       uri: "file:directory_path"
       steps:
         - setHeader:
               name: "directory"
               simple: "${headers.CamelFileParent}"
         - aggregate:
              aggregationStrategy: "GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy"
              correlationExpression:
                 simple: "${headers.directory}"
              completionSize: 3
```

This however doesnt work and throws an "Definition has no childer on Aggregate[${headers.directory} -> []]"

Any pointer or hint to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to add some kind of output from the aggregator, eg when those 3 files are aggregated together, what should happen next.